# Cassandra compare timestamp with currentdate

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

Trying to find the count for currendate in Cassandra like using the below query.

```
select count(*) from xyz.abctable  where toDate(datetime)>=toDate(now());
```

This is not working and gives an error message:

> SyntaxException: line 1:55 no viable alternative at input '(' (...)
>   from xyz.zbctable where toDate
>
> Data format for datetime, this needs to be compared with current and list the count for currentdate.
>       2017-02-23 22:41:12.386000+0000

Comment: Have you tried dateOf()? https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html